# Show index page for all links to folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder named "keywords" for my website, such as this: http://www.mysite.com/keywords/

In the folder I only have an index.php file. Regardless of what someone types in after the folder, I need the index.php to show. For example, http://www.mysite.com/keywords/this-is-a-test should show the index.php file's content but without changing the URL.

Everything I've tried seems to fail - I'm working with the .htaccess in my /keywords/ folder. Regardless of what I put there I seem to keep getting a 404 error. Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's something small and simple that I just don't know how to do.

This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule - index.php [L]
```

The problem with this is that it only work when going to links with a dash in them.

For example,

```
http://www.mysite.com/keywords/testing-this
```

does work.  But this does not work:

```
http://www.mysite.com/keywords/testingthis
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   #make sure your website is located in root directory, if not you have to add directory here...
RewriteRule ^keywords/testingthis$ /keywords/index.php$1 [L]
```